# How to tie a dynamic outcome with a time stamp

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7, datetime, dynamic

For purposes of time, this code is for example only.

I want to know the best way to tie a dynamic outcome with a time stamp, rendering that specific outcome static for a call back.

`from datetime import datetime dateTimeObj = datetime.now()`

`timestamp = str(dateTimeObj)`

(// = Im not quite sure how this would be structured but I imagine its something along the lines of: )

```
#dynamic data = x`
#timestamp = 2020-07-04 02:05:29
x = 18
print(x),timestamp

#CODE THAT TIES TIMESTAMP WITH X // tsmark = (x), timestamp

#20 MINUTES LATER
#timestamp = 2020-07-04 02:25:02

x = 109

print(x),timestamp

#CODE THAT TIES NEW TIMESTAMP WITH NEW X RESULT // ntsmark = (x), timestamp
```

The purpose of this would then be to find the difference in the result of X based off time.

`difin = tsmark - ntsmark`

```
print(difin)
#Outcome
-91
```

What would be a correct method, or format to accomplish a task like this?

I really appriciate all inputs.

Many Thanks.

Comment: So you are looking for a data structure to store a time series? What's the relation to Excel? Also, are you using Python 2.7? Your code suggests Python 3

Comment: Correct, I am looking for a data structure to store a time series. I am using pandas to extract dynamic data which is the relation to Excel. This data needs to be extracted and identified by time. Although my code suggests Python 3; I am using Python 2.7.

Comment: A list that holds time-value tuples might be an option? Lists are pretty nice for dynamic updates; finally you could convert to a pandas Series e.g. for export to Excel